# How to implement the idea of objects that access objects of other classes?

Tags: java, oop, class

Say I want to implement a work place. There are objects of class `Employee` and there is also a class `WorkArrangement`, which is like a box into which the employees submit their desired shifts for the next week. (The manager then empties the box and uses this information to arrange shifts for the next week).

The problem is, that the code in the class `Employee` doesn't know the object `box` (of class `WorkArrangement`), so I can't write a method which says "put your next week shifts in the box". I can send the `box` object as a parameter to the constructor of `Employee`, but it looks like a bad design in the sense of OOP.

So, is it a bad design?
If it is, then what is a possible solution?

Comment: What if the employee maintained their own list of desired shifts (box)  and then the employee can pass this to the WorkArrangement class which will maintain a list of all employee boxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds more like there's a `Box` (could just be a list) that takes `Shift`s, and an `Employee` has multiple collections of `Shift`s, `desiredShifts` and `actualShifts`.

The `Manager` then looks at each employee's desired shifts, juggles everything around, and assigns actual shifts to each employee, and/or puts them in a shared structure for use in a company calendar.

Comment: How he looks at employee's desired shifts? The `Manager` code should know there are instances of `Employee`'s, and he cannot know that, unless we pass him employees as parameters, which is the thing that looked ugly to me in the first place.

Comment: @Leif - the assignment of shifts is Business Logic and deserves its own class/classes. The Manager object doesn't do that, but you could require that a Manager object be available to the `ShiftJuggler` as the manager under whose authority this shift juggling is going on.

Comment: @LeifEricson No, as I said, there's an intermediary between the two classes. What that looks like is essentially arbitrary--I used a simple collection. Could be a message queue, could be observer/observable, anything.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, I would use event-driven logic (e.g. [using property change listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/propertychangelistener.html)). Once an `Employee` instance is ready to submit the desired shifts, fire off an event (e.g. `PropertyChangeEvent`). And in this event object, pass the shift information and other relevant information. From there, the receiver (i.e. `WorkArrangement`) can do what it pleases with such information (e.g. firing off another change event that notifies the `Manager` that is has received shift information).

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward approach would be for WorkArrangement to have a method where the Employee submits requests.  e.g.

```
public void requestShift(Employee employee, Shift requestedShift);
```

This way Employeee doesn't know how or what WorkArrangement does with the requests (they may get thrown into the trash for all you know!) but it knows how to sumbit a request.  You might need an argument for which week it is, but I'd prefer that already be in WorkArrangement, e.g. every week you construct a new WorkArrangement() for that week.  Later on, Employee could find out what they got via a call:

```
 public Shift getActualShift(Employee employee);
```

BTW, this guides us to a better name than "WorkArrangement", which doesn't really mean a whole lot:  something like "WeeklySchedule".  Not all class names can be simple and clear, but when one of the first classes you design has a fuzzy name, that's a sign that you are not on the right track.

If you really don't want WeeklySchedule to know what an Employee is, note that the argument is really just used as an identifier, on which you will use equals() (and probably hashCode()) at some point.  So that argument could be an Object, an integer or String employeeID, etc...